# can I say "why aren't we pinging"?

Tags: vocabulary

I would like to ask, but in an original and funny way 
"why haven't we been  texting/emailing/whatsapping etc..each other lately?"

This verb, "to ping", seemed the right one.

but I am not sure it is understandable and?or correct if I say
"Why haven't we been pinging lately?"

Comment: I assume you mean "pinging each other." I suggest you edit your question to clarify what you are saying.  Otherwise, "why aren't we pinging"  sounds like you could be trying to check the existence of or the online status of a machine.

Comment: Thank you. I see. Would you say that "why haven't we be pinging each other" would sound ok? I mean, I know it is a bit odd... but the objective it is for me to be a bit outside the line but understandable.

Comment: Pinging each other doesn't sound strange to me.  It makes perfect sense considering that we use ping at work to reference IM'ing each other.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  One comment- you may want to review the rules of "than" and "then".  You should have used "then" in your answer to me.  Let me know if you have any questions about this and we can take it offline from this discussion.

Comment: I've never really heard "pinging" used to describe an ongoing 2-way conversation. One person can certainly "ping" another, but in the original computer meaning, a "ping" is a single message that is either echoed back to the sender, or not. And that's mostly how I've heard it used in regular conversation... though, to be fair, most of the people I talk to are computer geeks who would know that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're entering the world of slang where words' meanings shift unexpectedly, so take this answer with a grain of salt.

This kind of use of *ping* comes from computer programmers.  There is a computer network utility called "ping" which measures the time it takes a message to get from one computer to another and back. If I feel like my internet connection is poor, I might `ping` a server to see if the message is taking a long to time be sent, or sent back.

This computer networking use comes from active sonar terminology, in which a *ping* is the pulse of sound the transmitter emits. Picture a scene from a movie set on a submarine: the sonar technician looks at a green and black screen, there's a "ping" sound and the screen flashes as the pulse of sound shoots out from the sub.

In both the network utility and the sonar case, the *ping* is a signal that's sent out and which bounces back to us and informs us about the presence or state of something (a server, a rocky sea floor, or what have you).

From those uses, a less specific use has evolved: *to send a message to notify, or request a status update from someone*.

As in: *I thought Alice was supposed to have deployed that code last night.  I'll ping her to see what the status is.*

This use still retains a reasonable connection to the original meaning - my text/email is like a sonar *ping*: *PING* "Alice, where are you?" *PING* "Here's my status..."

From here, the word took on an even broader meaning:

> **Ping** *verb*
>
> *informal* to send an email or text message:
>   *Ping me an email.*
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ping

"Ping me an email" sounds terrible to me, but supposedly someone speaks this way.

---

So, should you say, "we haven't been pinging"?

Well, according to the *Cambridge Dictionary* it appears to be acceptable. I would definitely not say this, based on my understanding of the history of the term. This kind of use ("Ping me an email") makes it sound like the speaker is not very familiar with the term, perhaps just heard some developers at his company talking about pinging something or someone.

Hopefully you now have enough information to make an informed decision for yourself.

Comment: Since "pinging" is checking status, it's really a use of email, not all emails sent for any reason. So I would say, "I'll work on the project, if you don't hear from me in a week, ping me about it." But I wouldn't say, "I'll ping you the quote". The second is not checking status/existence. It's a neologism, so Cambridge might be right in 20 years from now, but this year, "ping" and "email" are not synonymous in many circles (at least not in California where I reside).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, it is probably not a great idea to use "to ping" in this case. Any suggestion to make this boring question  "why haven't we been texting etc..each other lately?" more interesting?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but in all cases when a person asked to "ping" them, they were asking to remind them of something or check their status, just like this answer and BenL's comment indicate. Other dictionaries, such as the [Farlex dictionary of idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ping) and the [Dictionary of Unfamiliar Words](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ping) also support this. It looks like yet another oversight or undue oversimplification on Cambridge Dictionary's part.

Answer (score 0):

**to ping**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144138?rskey=UhusNo&result=6#eid)

> colloq. To send (a person) an electronic communication such as an
>   email, text, etc.; to send (an email, text, etc.) to a person.
>   Frequently with direct and indirect object: to send (a person) (an
>   email, text, etc.).

As in:

- > 2001   Rushville (Indiana) Republican 15 Oct. 4/2   If you have any
  >   questions, give me a call here at the office or ping me an e-mail.
  -

> 2015   K. Kwan China Rich Girlfriend i. xii. 112   The phone inside
>   her minaudière gave a quick buzz, and she smiled, thinking Michael
>   must have just read her mind and pinged her.

**Ping me**! In AmE, was for geeks and nerds.  Now it seems to be used slightly more, especially as usual by segment of population born into internet existence!

Comment: Thank you. I saw "to pinge" used this way too "I am aware of times where work has been pinged my way etc.." I suppose it means "work has been sent my way", right? but probably there are nuances